# Convert column value into multiple rows in a range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with price range.
How can I create a new table where each row has unique price value. 
Thanks.!

input table:

```
min_price ,        max_price ,       item  
3 ,               5 ,              apple  
2 ,               6 ,              plum  
21 ,              25  ,            banana
```

output table

```
price  ,         item  
3   ,            apple  
4   ,            apple  
5 ,              apple  
2 ,              plum  
3 ,              plum  
4 ,              plum  
5 ,              plum  
6 ,              plum  
21 ,             banana  
22 ,             banana  
23 ,             banana  
24 ,             banana  
25 ,             banana
```

Comment: ENOUGH WITH THE SHOUTING ALREADY

Answer (score 3):

You can create a table that contains all the numbers you care about:

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (
    n INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY n
);
INSERT INTO numbers (n) VALUES (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 1000);
```

Then you can write a join:

```
SELECT n.n AS price, i.item
FROM numbers AS n
JOIN input AS i ON n BETWEEN min_price AND max_price
ORDER BY item, price
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution first;

```
select sequence.number as price, products.item
from sequence, products -- Note, no join!
where sequence.number >= products.min_price
       and sequence.number <= products.max_price
```

You need to generate a sequence table which contains a list of numbers that maxes out at the highest possible value you would use. Once you have that you can join to this table without a clause to generate every possible combination of the union, and then simply filter by your range.

Example sequence table

```
  +----------+
  |  number  |
  +----------+
  | 0        |
  | 1        |
  | 2        |
  | ..       |
  | 99999999 |
  +----------+
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as my answer, which I posted 20 minutes earlier?

Comment: @Bamar - It is - apologies. I loaded the page when it had no answer and by the time I submitted saw your almost identical result. Great minds think alike.